# Sharing internet from lan (single ethernet cable) to multiple devices

Tags: router, lan, ethernet

My serviced office provides internet via a single ethernet cable (internet via lan). I wish to share this to multiple devices both wirelessly and over ethernet.

The office has given me specific IP, subnet, primary+secondary DNS details to access the internet over the ethernet cable.

What type of device do I need so that I can share this ethernet-internet connection to my own devices?

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple router with wireless capabilities, no?